# SQL Count with multiple Group By

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if a table could be created using count within multiple group by functions or how to possibly do this.

The goal is to create a table from our DB showing ethnicity numbers of our students based on year in the program.

| Year | Black/AA | Hispanic/Latinx | Asian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | # | # | # |
| 2023 | # | # | # |
| 2024 | # | # | # |

But can't figure out how to make SQL group them all effectively.

The data set looks like

| Student_id | year | ethnicity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023 | 3 |
| 4 | 2023 | 2 |
| 5 | 2024 | 3 |
| 6 | 2024 | 1 |

| Ethnicity_id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Black/AA |
| 2 | Hispanic/Latinx |
| 3 | Asian |

Comment: If you have clearly defined criteria for each group it's quite simple. Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: It's not very clear what you need. Here's a good reference on how to structure a question to get helpful answers https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ For example here, it looks like you've provided some expected output, number of students of each ethnicity aggregated by year, but without knowing the source/input data it's difficult to help you get there.

Comment: you probably want a pivot.  which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server!

Answer (score 0):

you probably want a pivot. the pivot syntax is different depending on your rdbms.  since you did not provide a rdmbs I will post a more generic solution using the case statement.

```
select year,
 sum(case when ethnicity_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) "Black/AA",
 sum(case when ethnicity_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end)  "Hispanic/Latinx",
sum(case when ethnicity_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end)  "Asian"
from student_data
group by year
order by year
```

Comment: I think you want `sum` rather than `count`

Comment: oops yep sorry about that, I updated

Comment: should also use double-quotes around the column aliases, single-quotes are string literals

Comment: You could use `count` though, as long as you remove `else 0` and rely on null